# Unusual C pointer behaviour

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following snippet of code:

```
uint8_t     *ptrconfig;
uint8_t     *ptrspi;

ptrconfig = &TempDeviceConfig.ConfigSize;
ptrspi = &spi_out_array[0];
for ( Count = 0U; Count < DEVICE_USER_SETTINGS_WORDCOUNT +1U; Count++ )
{
    *ptrspi++ = *ptrconfig++;
}
```

However it is not working as expected breakpointing on the second line shows that the address of `TempDeviceConfig.ConfigSize` is `0x2BD5` however the address the pointer points to is `0x216F`.

Why do I get an unexpected value of pointer?

EDIT:
A bit of clarification, I can't say exactly what is inside TempDeviceConfig because I need to be careful how much code appears on the internet, but yes it is a struct and it contains a total of 50+ bytes which are to be written to an external flash chip over SPI. My aim here is to copy the struct into the SPI array which sends the data out.

Comment: If it were a type you wouldn't be able to take its address.

Comment: @Barmar yah it was a dumb question. What I was really trying to get at was can we see the types of TempDeviceConfig and ConfigSize

Comment: Looks like an overly complicated way to perform a memcpy() `memcpy (spi_out_array, &TempDeviceConfig.ConfigSize, DEVICE_USER_SETTINGS_WORDCOUNT+1);`

Comment: can you show `TempDeviceConfig.ConfigSize` type?

Comment: which pointer have the bad expected address? what second line is breakpointed?

Comment: Note that while `unsigned char` can legally alias any object, `uint8_t` cannot do so unless it happens to be defined as `unsigned char`. So you should be using `unsigned char` explicitly.

Comment: It seems suspicious that you are copying configuration data out of a variable named "config *size*".

Comment: A wild guess: get rid of the `.ConfigSize` and the `+1U`.

Comment: What is the declaration of `TempDeviceConfig` and how did you determine the address of `TempDeviceConfig.ConfigSize`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uint8_t     *ptrconfig;
...
ptrconfig = &TempDeviceConfig.ConfigSize;
```

Apparently `TempDeviceConfig` is a struct (or union?), and `ConfigSize` is a member which is of type `uint8_t`.

```
*ptrspi++ = *ptrconfig++;
```

`ConfigSize` is a single `uint8_t` object. You can advance the pointer only once; it then points just past the object, and cannot be dereferenced. Your code assumes that `ptrconfig` points to an element of an array of `uint8_t`. It doesn't. It doesn't make sense to loop over a single object.

I can't guess what the code *should* be doing without seeing the declarations of the objects you're using. But if your intent is to copy the entire structure (including any padding) into `spi_out_array`, a call to `memcpy()` is a much simpler way to do it. (Copying raw structure contents to an external interface can be quite error-prone, but if the written data is only read by the current system it could be ok.)

If `memcpy()` is not available because you're programming for a small embedded system, you can easily implement it yourself, either as a function or as inline code. For example:

```
struct foo { /* ... */ } obj;
unsigned char out_array[sizeof obj];   // or perhaps bigger
unsigned char *from = (unsigned char*)&obj;
unsigned char *to = out_array; // or &out_array[0]
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof obj; i ++) {
    *to++ = *from++;
}
```

I've defined `out_array` as an array of `unsigned char`, because that's the most portable 1-byte type in C; an object's *representation* is defined as a sequence of `unsigned char` values. But you can almost certainly use `uint8_t` instead.

If your goal is to copy the entire representation of the structure as raw bytes, it doesn't make sense to refer to a particular member; just treat the entire structure as a byte sequence.

But first check whether your implementation supports `memcpy` (if so, it should be declared in `<string.h>`). "Freestanding implementations" aren't required to support any standard library functions, but yours might support some subset of the hosted standard library.

Comment: Actually, you can increment `ptrconfig` as many times as you like - pointers don't know how big the object they are pointing into is.  After a while, attempting to dereference it bring back garbage and then eventually seg fault.

Comment: @JeremyP: If `ptrconfig` points to a single object, incrementing it more than once, or incrementing it just once and dereferencing it, has undefined behavior. (The worst possible outcome is that it appears to "work".)

Comment: A bit of clarification, I can't say exactly what is in TempDeviceConfig because I need to be careful how much code appears on the internet, but yes it is a struct and it contains a total of 50+ bytes which are to be written to an external flash chip over SPI. My aim here is to copy the struct into the SPI array which sends the data out.

Comment: @user3628620: Ok, but `TempDeviceConfig.ConfigSize` is a `uint8_t`, right? Why are you trying to iterate over a single `uint8_t` object?

Comment: unless I'm mistaken *ptrtemp++ should move the pointer to the next address which in this case would be the next item in the struct.

Comment: @Deamonata: It *might* do that -- if there happens to be no padding. It might make sense to assign the address of the structure (converted to `uint8_t*`) to `ptrconfig`, if the intent is to copy the entire structure. Is `ConfigSize` the *first* declared member of the struct? See the last paragraph of my updated answer.

Comment: Configsize is the first member and TempDeviceConfig is a packed struct. with regards to memcpy I'm not sure that is available as unless I'm mistaken that requires stdio library which I don't have access to because I'm developing on a microchip (msp430)

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, it's undefined behaviour officially, but in practice, on every single implementation I have used ever, you can increment as much as you like and dereferencing will either return the content of memory above the legitimate object or seg fault if the virtual address is not mapped.